# what is correct size of a icon for mdip and what is the correct way to design layout for different densities

Tags: android, android-layout

I have gone through all the websites.I know mdpi is like 1X but what is correct size for mdpi .I have psd of 3000*3000 I have resized it to 800*1200 and now if i crop images will be 2x and now I make according to all sizes like 1x ,1.5x and save in corresponding folders.Is this the correct way to do? but if i do that i am not getting correct images sizes like some icons are blur.I have given the some text to textview it shows good in more pixel mobile but in low pixel mobile the text will big size not same as more pixel can any suggest me what is going wrong and am i following the correct procedure?As per android developer site , I am using sw320 and sw480 layout folders.[image: less pixel image]

Thanks in advance. [image: more pixel image]

Comment: Please [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996396/2826147)

Comment: if your are looking for `ActionBar` Icons go through [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60)

Comment: ok,but my question is for all icons for application